# Using GCM to send push notification from one activity to another - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am currently programming an android application in Android Studio. I am trying to implement a push notification service with GCM. The push notification will be sent from one user account to another user account, the second user will accept and then the two accounts will be linked. I have the two accounts set up on a mySQL server using 000webhost.com. I tried to followed this tutorial , [link](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/push-notification-using-gcm-in-android.html), to implement GCM but I can't figure out how I send and receive the notification.
This is where I get the registration ID:

```
package com.jack.pointcollector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GCMClientManager {
    // Constants
    public static final String TAG = "GCMClientManager";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    // Member variables
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private String regID;
    private String projectNumber;
    private Activity activity;

    public GCMClientManager(Activity activity, String projectNumber) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.projectNumber = projectNumber;
        this.gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity);
    }
    /**
    * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
    */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
    // Register if needed or fetch from local store
    public void registerIfNeeded(final RegistrationCompletedHandler handler)             {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            regID = getRegistrationId(getContext());
            if (regID.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground(handler);
            } else { // got id from cache
                Log.i(TAG, regID);
                handler.onSuccess(regID, false);
            }
        } else { // no play services
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground(final RegistrationCompletedHandler handler) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getContext());
                    }
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getContext());
                    regID = instanceID.getToken(projectNumber, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    Log.i(TAG, regID);
                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(getContext(), regID);
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                    handler.onFailure("Error :" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                return regID;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String regId) {
                if (regId != null) {
                    handler.onSuccess(regId, true);
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *     registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.apply();
    }
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private Context getContext() {
        return activity;
    }
    private Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
    public static abstract class RegistrationCompletedHandler {
        public abstract void onSuccess(String registrationId, boolean isNewRegistration);
        public void onFailure(String ex) {
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
            Log.e(TAG, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my GCMListnerService class:

```
package com.jack.pointcollector;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class PushNotificationManager extends GcmListenerService{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        childNotification(from);
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
    }
    private AlertDialog childNotification(String name) {
        AlertDialog.Builder response = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getBaseContext());
        response.setMessage(name + " has added you as their child. Is this correct?");
        response.setTitle("Point Collector");
        response.setPositiveButton("Correct", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        response.setNegativeButton("I don't know them", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        response.setCancelable(false);
        return response.create();
    }
}
```

and finally the class the I want to send the notification from

```
package com.jack.pointcollector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Add_Child extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button bAddChild;
    EditText etUsername, etEmail;
    String PROJECT_NUMBER = "76770391940";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__child);

        bAddChild = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.child_email);

        bAddChild.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.addButton:
                GCMClientManager pushClientManager = new GCMClientManager(this, PROJECT_NUMBER);
                pushClientManager.registerIfNeeded(new GCMClientManager.RegistrationCompletedHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String registrationId, boolean isNewRegistration) {
                        Log.d("Registration id", registrationId);
                        //send this registrationId to your server
                        toServer(registrationId);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String ex) {
                        super.onFailure(ex);
                    }
                });

                break;
        }
    }
    private void toServer(final String id) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://point_collector.netau.net/");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("id", id);
                    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(query);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();
                    //Gets the response code to ensure this was succesful.
                    int code = conn.getResponseCode();
                    Log.d("code", Integer.toString(code));
                    conn.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have looked and loads of video tutorials as well as online tutorials and can't figure it out at all. If anybody can help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

edit - Still really stuck on this if anybody at all could offer some insight!

Comment: So what happens. Have you checked your log to see if any errors occur. 
Does the registration occur correctly?

Comment: Yes the registration occurs but when I log out of the account then log back into a different account I get a FATAL error, with a java RunTimeException

Comment: I am able to get the registration ID so I assume this works correctly but I don't know what to do from here? How do I create a notification to send to the other activity

Comment: You should have a look at this sample, it demonstrates both the client and server sides of GCM. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm